# Spring Cloud Config and static content

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a application that uses Spring cloud config (--spring.profiles.active=native) and also serves up some html pages within the same application. All is fine until I introduce static resources (src/main/resources/css/bootstrap-switch.css). The URL calls to http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap-switch.css fails with this Exception:

```
{"timestamp":1438114326940,"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException","message":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/css/bootstrap-switch.css"}
```

When I disable the @EnableConfigServer, the URL returns the CSS content. I am on Spring Cloud Config version 1.0.2.

Here's my minimalist code that can reproduce this issue:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableConfigServer
    public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
    }
    }


    @Configuration
    @SpringBootApplication
    class ApplicationConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public TestController testController() {
        return new TestController();
      }
      @Bean
      public MvcController mvcController() {
        return new MvcController();
      }
    }


    @RestController
    class TestController {
      @RequestMapping("/test")
      @ResponseBody
      public String test() {
        return "hello world";
      }
    }

    @Controller
    class MvcController {
      @RequestMapping("/landing")
      public String landingPage() {
        return "landing";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Config server by default has an api that matches `/*/*`.  You can move the root of the api by changing `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=myroot`.